# Is there an API to find Device ID for Samsung TV in Tizen for React Native apps?

Tags: react-native, tizen, tizen-studio, deviceid, tizen-sdb

I'm trying to build a Tizen app in a React Native framework. One concern is to find the device id (whether physical tv or an emulator).

Consider the below code snippet:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <Text style={styles.textH3}>
                     {`platform: ${deviceId}`}  //How can I show deviceId here? Or device-specific info?
              </Text>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Any idea how to get the `deviceId` (something like its `UUID`) in the above snippet, from the `Tizen SDK`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) package

This package has `DeviceInfo.getDeviceId()` [method](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getdeviceid) for getting running device Id

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that similar to the model number? Apologies for not being specific enough, but I'm looking for something that uniquely identifies the device, a la `UUID` or something like that.

Comment: what is about other methods in this package? like https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#getserialnumber